# How to select from data with variable Database and Table

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Is there any way to select from a variable table name database name and value?

I'm trying to a check the column value is exist from the below way. I forced do this way because the table name and column names and values are variable...

This is used in a Stored Procedure File.

I want something like:

```
SELECT 1
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA= 'database1'
      AND TABLE_NAME= 'table1'
      AND COLUMN_NAME = 'clmn_id_fk'
      AND 'database1.table1.clmn_id_fk'=2218
```

I am not able to find a result.

Comment: ya it is possible.assuming u r using php.just assign the table name to a variable and than use that variable in your mysql query.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but this code is called by a stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

You can take inspiration from a stored procedure as shown below. Change all that is necessary to achieve the solution you want, it is very important to include all the relevant restrictions and validations.

```sql
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */

DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_check`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_check`(`p_table_schema` VARCHAR(64), `p_table_name` VARCHAR(64), `p_column_name` VARCHAR(64), `p_value` INT)
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT NULL
            FROM `information_schema`.`columns`
            WHERE `table_schema` = `p_table_schema` AND
            `table_name` = `p_table_name` AND
            `column_name` = `p_column_name`) THEN
        SET @qry := CONCAT('SELECT IF(COUNT(`', `p_column_name`, '`), 1, 0) AS `EXISTS` FROM `', `p_table_schema`, '`.`', `p_table_name`, '` WHERE `', `p_column_name`, '` = ', `p_value`);
        PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    ELSE
        SELECT 0 AS `EXISTS`;
    END IF;

END$$

DELIMITER ;

CALL `sp_check`('database1', 'table1', 'clmn_id_fk', 2218);
```